# Apache says ERROR 324 when trying to do SoapClient() (under Yii)

Tags: php, apache, soap, yii

The question is self explanatory.

I had an apparently working piece of code in the past, but today it started to crash.
With "echo" traces I've isolated the offending line of code, but I'm lost right now.

```
...
...
echo "hi<br>";
return;

$soap = new SoapClient ('SOMEURL:8088/somePath?wsdl');

echo "hi 2<br>";
```

If I keep the "return" line, it just says "hi". And everything ends ok.
If I remove the "return" line, Apache (?) just crashes, with a "324 error" (under chromium). The "hi2" line never gets printed. So the offending line is the one with the SoapClient call.

The funny thing is if I type that Soap connection string onto a web-browser tab, it just loads the XML with the wsdl data, so the Soap server is apparently working.

If I just let SoapClient run under my php code, Apache just says "Error 324: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

What should I do from my PHP/Yii/Apache side of things? How could I trace more?

As I said I'm lost and desperate.

Answer (score 1):

Question: have you just moved that code into a PHP 5.3 namespaced class? You may need to put an escape in front of SoapClient to use the global object:

```
$soap = new \SoapClient();
```

Comment: It's been erratic. 

Apparently it seemed that your "backslash trick" did some magic the other day and the whole process worked again, but some days later (withouth changing my code at all) it stopped working. 

Then I changed onto a "backslash-less version" (like the one I had on the first place), and again it worked again... Until today which it refuses to work again.

I'm using OSX-Maverick and XAMPP 1.7.3